# SQL: walk through a graph with circles

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, graph

I have a table of objects with attributes. Some object share the same attribute, in which case I consider them to be connected through their common attribute:

```
object   attribute
  1          a
  1          b
  2          a
  2          c
  3          b
  3          d
  4          c
  5          d
  6          e
  7          e
```

Think about it as a network:

```
5 - d - 3 - b - 1 - a - 2 - c - 4    7 - e - 6
```

In this example, the network is just a line. It can be a tree, have circles etc. I need to find the set of all objects that are connected with object `1` through common attributes and other objects. In this case, it's the set `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

I tried using recursion:

```
with graph as (select object, attribute
               from   my_table where object = 1
               union all
               select my_table.object, my_table.attribute
               from   graph join my_table on my_table.attribute = graph.attribute
                                             and my_table.object <> graph.object
              )
select * from graph
```

It works for non-circular graphs, but when I have circles, I keep adding the same elements in the `graph` table. How can I keep track of the elements that I already added?

EDIT: It actually doesn't work for any graph, because after reaching element `3`  it goes back to element `1` and bounces between them for the end of the times.

UPDATE: The answer didn't work for me, as it is passing through the same nodes again and again (I have circular relations between objects), but it put me on the right track! After a long struggle with SQL no permitting to do anything inside the CTE I found this to be executed quick enough for my graph:

```
drop table if exists #my_table
create table #my_table 
        (obj int
        ,attribute varchar(10)
        )

insert into #my_table values
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, 'a'), 
(2, 'c'),
(3, 'b'),
(3, 'd'), 
(4, 'c'),
(5, 'd'),
(6, 'e'),
(7, 'e')


;with grouped as (select 1 step
                        -- this will be the full history of all objects and attributes that are connected to the initial object
                        ,convert(varchar(max), stuff((select    ', ' + convert(varchar(10), dc.obj) + ' - ' + dc.attribute 
                                                    FROM    #my_table dc
                                                    where   obj = 1
                                                    for xml path ('')), 1, 2, '')
                                ) history
                union ALL
                SELECT  step + 1 as step
                        ,convert(varchar(max), grouped.history + (SELECT    ', ' + convert(varchar(10), dc2.obj) + ' - ' + dc2.attribute
                                                                from    #my_table dc
                                                                JOIN    #my_table dc2 on dc2.obj = dc.obj 
                                                                        -- the new object should be connected to an attribute in our history
                                                                WHERE   grouped.history like '%' + convert(varchar(10), dc.attribute) + '%'
                                                                        -- but this should be a new object (not in the history yet)
                                                                        and grouped.history not like '%' + convert(varchar(10), dc2.obj) + ' - ' + dc.attribute + '%'
                                                                for xml path (''))
                                ) history 
                FROM    grouped
                where   grouped.history is not null
                )
select  * from grouped
```

Comment: use distinct and union instead of union all

Comment: @apomene but I can't use `distinct`, `union`, `group by` clauses in the recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to store the information about the nodes that have been traveled.

```
declare @my table(obj int, attr char(1));

insert into @my(obj,attr) values
  (1,'a'),
  (1,'b'),
  (2,'a'),
  (2,'c'),
  (3,'b'),
  (3,'d'),
  (4,'c'),
  (5,'d'),
  (6,'e'),
  (7,'e');

with
  t as(
    select 1 lv,obj,attr,row_number() over(order by(select 0)) gr,
      cast('/'+str(obj,5)+right(space(4)+attr,5)+'/' as varchar(max)) hy
    from @my
    where obj=5
    union all
    select t.lv+1,my.obj,my.attr,t.gr,
      t.hy+str(my.obj,5)+right(space(4)+my.attr,5)+'/'
    from t join @my my on t.obj=my.obj or t.attr=my.attr
    where t.hy not like '%/'+str(my.obj,5)+right(space(4)+my.attr,5)+'/%'
  ),
  p as(
    select *,row_number() over(partition by gr order by lv desc) tp
    from t
  )
select * from p where tp=1
option(maxrecursion 0);
```